# Insert Row between range of numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel have 1 Column and 10 Rows of sequential numbers. I want to create a macro which could start from top value of column then insert 2 rows with the first value of list and then move on to second value and do same and so on.

```
Values Column
1
2
3

Result Column
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: So you are saying insert 2 rows, but your example shows extra columns... what would it be? rows or columns? .nvm... was edited.

Comment: @erazorv4: I tried to insert rows but received Error 1004

Comment: @DarXyde It is rows, thank you for editing

Comment: @Aaron6 We can't help you if you don't show the code, Error 1004 could be caused by a lot of things. [edit] your question with the code you're trying, and what line the error is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do:

```vb
Sub insertRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim R As Long

    For R = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        ws.Rows(R & ":" & R + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(R, 1), ws.Cells(R + 1, 1)) = ws.Cells(R + 2, 1).Value
    Next R

End Sub
```

PS: this is working its up from the bottom... not top to bottom.

Comment: It works well. I just changed loop for R from 2 to 1 and it included first value as well. Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: I've left that out thinking of headers, but yeah. Glad it works for you.

Comment: Can you help me with this solution as well please thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/q/56360207/11468228